# how to flip image in dynamic multiple slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


             $('.multiple-items').slick({
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows:true,
        });
        });


    </script>
    <style>
        .slick-prev
        {
            left: 15px; /* left:30px;
            left:0px;*/
        }

        .slick-next
        {
            right: 15px; /*  right:0px;
            right:13px;*/
        }

        .arrowhide .slick-arrow
        {
            opacity: 0;
            transition: ease all 0.5s;
            -webkit-transition: ease all 0.5s;
            -o-transition: ease all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: ease all 0.5s;
        }
        .arrowhide:hover .slick-arrow
        {
            opacity: 9;
        }
        .slick-prev, .slick-next
        {
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            z-index: 9;
            background: gainsboro;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
        .slick-prev:hover, .slick-next:hover
        {
            background: #00AEEF;
        }
        .slick-dots
        {
            bottom: 0;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .slick-dots li button
        {
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
        .imgslide
        {
            margin-top: 4px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: solid 1px #E4E4E4;
        }

        img
        {
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: 154px;
            width: 263px;
            float: right;
            padding: 4px;
            margin-top: 2px;
        }



        .slick-prev:hover, .slick-next:hover
        {
            color: transparent;
            outline: none;
            background: #00AEEF;
        }
        .arrowhide .slick-arrow
        {
            opacity: 0;
            transition: ease all 0.5s;
            -webkit-transition: ease all 0.5s;
            -o-transition: ease all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: ease all 0.5s;
        }


        .multiple-items img
        {
            display: block;
            width: 104%;
            height: 49%;
            padding-left: 7px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            margin-top: -8px;
        }
        . .multiple-items img
        {
            display: block;
            width: 96%;
            padding-left: 25px; /*  height: 55%;
            padding-right: -26px;
            margin-top: -8px;
            margin-right: 30px;
            padding: 1px;
            margin-top: -68px;
            padding-top: -27px;*/
        }
        .multiple-items
        {
            width: 560px;
            height: 180px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .slick-initialized .multiple-items
        {
            display: block;
            height: 359px;
            width: 131px;
        }
        .flip
        {
            height: 199px;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .flip img
        {
            width: 300px;
            height: auto;
        }
        .flip .back
        {
            background: #2184cd;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="float: left;">
            <div id="slider" class=" multiple-items" runat="server">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%--</div>--%>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

    enter code here
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strHtm = string.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/pic/"));
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            strHtm += @"<div id='DivNew" + i + @"'>
                            <img src='images/pic/" + fileName + @"'  height=50 width=50 />
                        </div>";
            i++;
        }

        slider.InnerHtml = strHtm;




    }
}
```

Hello i am working on dynamic multiple slick slider.I want my slider image should me flip on mousehover what should i do for it? above is my code using this it display slider with dynamic image but image are not getting flip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is your answer**

***In this it is not perfect work please put this code in your site***

```css
.slick-prev{
  left: 15px;
}
.slick-next{
  right: 15px;
}
.arrowhide .slick-arrow{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: ease all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: ease all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: ease all 0.5s;
}
.arrowhide:hover .slick-arrow{
  opacity: 9;
}
.slick-prev, .slick-next{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 9;
  background: gainsboro;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.slick-prev:hover, .slick-next:hover{
  background: #00AEEF;
}
.slick-dots{
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.slick-dots li button{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.imgslide{
  margin-top: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #E4E4E4;
}
.slick-prev:hover, .slick-next:hover{
  color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  background: #00AEEF;
}
.arrowhide .slick-arrow{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: ease all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: ease all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: ease all 0.5s;
}
.multiple-items{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.slick-initialized .multiple-items{
  display: block;
  height: 359px;
  width: 131px;
}
.flip{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.flip img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.flip .back{
  background: #2184cd;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Flip/1.1.2/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.multiple-items').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: true,
    });
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $(".flip").flip({
      trigger: 'hover'
    });
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $(".flip").flip({
      trigger: 'hover',
      axis: 'x'
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="float: left;">
    <div id="slider" class=" multiple-items">
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="front">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b8/d6/02/b8d60211137a9b9aca275adeb594d0c7.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b8/d6/02/b8d60211137a9b9aca275adeb594d0c7.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="front">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b8/d6/02/b8d60211137a9b9aca275adeb594d0c7.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b8/d6/02/b8d60211137a9b9aca275adeb594d0c7.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip">
        <div class="front">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b8/d6/02/b8d60211137a9b9aca275adeb594d0c7.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b8/d6/02/b8d60211137a9b9aca275adeb594d0c7.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: slidesToShow: 3, replace this

Comment: please help me how to bring dynamic image in slider

Comment: I don't know about dynamic, you create this div <div class="flip"> here your slide code </div>

Comment: 1. I was put code in answer. 2. search in this class flip div. 3. you remove all three flip div,  4. and replace that dynamic div code.

Comment: i am so new to this i don't know please write code properly and send

Comment: I told you first i am not developer so i don't know dynamic code.

Comment: then what should i do i am not getting anyting

Comment: in india u r from which place @hit place please tell me about dynamic please